# Writing multiple data types into a pre-existing file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay so I'm making a making a car parking system and am trying to store data into a pre-existing text file to read at a later date.

Storing the data works fine, using the code

```
Files.write(Paths.get("FilePath.txt"),"\r\nhello".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`
```

However, when I try to store multiple data types for example:

```
Files.write(
  Paths.get(
    "C:\\Users\\A612475\\Desktop\\Project1\\TextFiles\\TicketData.txt"),
    "\r\nhello" + regNo.getBytes(), 
    StandardOpenOption.APPEND
  );`
```

with regNo being declared as a string elsewhere, I get the following message:

The method `write(Path, byte[], OpenOption...)` in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments `(Path, String, StandardOpenOption)`

I can store the data in the string by writing the File.write method out dozens of times, but is there a more practical way to do this?

EDIT: Solution was found here: [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: Did you read this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Solved the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is simple, instead of passing a byte array you are passing a string. "\r\nhello" + regNo.getBytes() Is acts as a simple concatenation operation and thus what you are getting is a string, Thus this error.